# Exception has occurred: TypeError 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with Pandas in python I have 2 Dataframes that I am trying to pull infromation from one to the other.  Here is a example of the code.

```
    import pandas as pd

employees = {'Names': ['John','Jack','Frank','Mike'],
             'Employee_id': ['123', '124', '125', '126'],
             'Leader': ['','','','']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(employees, columns = ['Names', 'Employee_id', 'Leader'])

print(df1)

leader = {'Employee_id': ['123', '124', '125', '126'],
          'Supervisor': ['Nick', 'Jeff', 'Nick', 'Jeff']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(leader, columns = ['Employee_id', 'Supervisor'])
print(df2)

df1['Leader'] = df1['Employee_id'].map(lambda x: df2['Supervisor'] if df2['Employee_id'] in x else "")

print(df1)
```

Here is the error.

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Series
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `df2['Employee_id'] in x`, `x` is a string and `df2['Employee_id']` is a pandas series. Python doesn't know how to check for `series in big_string` operation. More specifically, it can only check for `some_string in big_string`.

IN your case, you can use `map` with a series:

```
df1['Leader'] = df1['Employee_id'].map(df2.set_index('Employee_id')['Supervisor'])
```

Output:

```
   Names Employee_id Leader
0   John         123   Nick
1   Jack         124   Jeff
2  Frank         125   Nick
3   Mike         126   Jeff
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In [79]: df = df1.merge(df2, on='Employee_id') 

In [80]: df
Out[80]: 
   Names Employee_id Leader Supervisor
0   John         123              Nick
1   Jack         124              Jeff
2  Frank         125              Nick
3   Mike         126              Jeff
```